# View A Base64 Encoded Page

Tags: javascript, file, base64

Might be too general question but anyway.

I have a link to a file on a server which is base64 encoded. I would like to be able to view this file decoded.

In order to achieve this, I am downloading the file content then inserting it into something like

```
<a href="data:image/png;base64,...(base64-encoded file content goes here)..."
  width="70" height="38" alt="image embedded using base64 encoding!"></a>
```

Then opening this link to view the file.

I was wondering if there is maybe a more elegant solution? For instance, can I view my original link decoded by passing in some parameter to the link or some such?

Ideally I am looking for a way to view it without having to download and decode it via JavaScript.

Comment: Have the courtesy to explain down votes please and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try `<img src="data:image/png;base64,...(base64-encoded file content goes here)..." />`

Live DEMO:

https://jsfiddle.net/anzrrogs/